# SQL Server 2012 queries: how to query 2 tables and filter results

Tags: sql-server

What's the best way to query two tables and use the results of query #1 to remove entries from query #2 results? I checked questions on combining results sets & deleting duplicates, but not quite what is needed.

All our users have role 1, advanced users have roles 1 AND 2, 3, 4, etc. The goal is a list of users who ONLY have role 1.

My approach so far (syntax help will be appreciated!):

Step 1:

```
select roles.user_id  as "AdvancedUsers" from roles where role > 1
```

Step 2:

```
select Users.ID, Users.email as "AllUsers" from users
```

Step 3 should remove `AdvancedUsers` from returned results of `AllUsers`

Hope that was clear.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT Users.ID, Users.email from users
WHERE Users.ID NOT IN (select roles.user_id from roles where role > 1)
```